# How to place Widget in destination in NavigationRail

Tags: flutter, material-ui, flutter-layout

I would like to know how to place a **`List<Widget> in destinations in NavigationRail`**

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NavigationRail(
      minWidth: width,
      selectedIndex: currentPageIndex,
      labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.all,
      onDestinationSelected: _setIndex,
      destinations: const [
        animatedNavigationItem(
          child: const NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home_rounded),
            label: 'Home',
          ), 
          index: 0,
        ),
        animatedNavigationItem(
          child: const NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(Icons.explore),
            label: 'Explore',
          ),
          index: 1,
        ),
        animatedNavigationItem(
          child: const NavigationDestination(
          icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark),
          label: 'Saved',
        ),
          index: 2,
        ),
        animatedNavigationItem(
          child: const NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(Icons.mail_rounded),
            label: 'Messages',
          ),
          index: 3,
        ),
        animatedNavigationItem(
          child: const NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person_rounded),
            label: 'Profile',
          ),
          index: 4,
        ),
      ]
    );
  }
```

But NavigationRail `{required List<NavigationRailDestination> destinations}`.
so I can’t place `Widget`.

I’d like to know how to change this to be able to place a `Widget`.

Error:`The element type 'Container' can't be assigned to the list type 'NavigationRailDestination'`.

as on **NavigationBar**

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NavigationBar(
      selectedIndex: currentPageIndex,
      labelBehavior: NavigationDestinationLabelBehavior.alwaysShow,
      onDestinationSelected: setIndex,
      height: height,
      destinations: [
        animatedNavigationItem(
          child: const NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home_rounded),
            label: 'Home',
          ), 
          index: 0,
        ),
        animatedNavigationItem(
          child: const NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(Icons.explore),
            label: 'Explore',
          ),
          index: 1,
        ),
        animatedNavigationItem(
          child: const NavigationDestination(
          icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark),
          label: 'Saved',
        ),
          index: 2,
        ),
        animatedNavigationItem(
          child: const NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(Icons.mail_rounded),
            label: 'Messages',
          ),
          index: 3,
        ),
        animatedNavigationItem(
          child: const NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person_rounded),
            label: 'Profile',
          ),
          index: 4,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

`{required List<Widget> destinations}`

Comment: Please do not provide sample code as an image, but as a code block so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`NavigationRailDestination` is NOT the same of the `NavigationDestination`

Use `NavigationRailDestination` on `NavigationRail` and

`NavigationDestination` on `NavigationBar`.

`Label` require `Text` widget on `NavigationRailDestination`. See the differences:

```dart
      NavigationDestination(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
        label: 'Home',
        selectedIcon: const Icon(Icons.home),
      ),    

    
      NavigationRailDestination(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
        label: Text('Home'),
        selectedIcon: const Icon(Icons.home),
      ),
```

AND Your function `animatedNavigationItem` has to return the same widget type, `NavigationDestination` OR `NavigationRailDestination`, in accord to the parent widget.

If you want to animate, it is better animate the icon widget.
try [AnimatedIcon](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AnimatedIcon-class.html) class, you can build your own animated icon.